# Minimum clearance between tree branches and overhead electrical (Indiana)

Tags: electrical, measuring

What is Indiana code for minimum clearance between power lines overhead and tree branches? I was able to find some things talking about how high cables should be off the ground, but nothing about tree branch clearance, is this a standard?

Comment: I'd contact your utility company and ask them.

Comment: People working near or machinery near the primary wires should be a minimum of 10 feet for up to 50Kv. Secondary wires should be a minimum of 5-10 feet away. I would think this distance would be the same for trees. This is what I have been taught, and I believe it is national. Primary = high voltage wires at top of pole. Secondary = lower set of wires after (below) transformer. This is 120-240 volts normal line voltage.